# Laptop battery drains faster in Ubuntu 16.04 when compared to other OS

Tags: 16.04, battery

The battery backup of my Lenovo G50-45 laptop is very low of around 3hrs on full charge.

This was approximately double when I was working with Windows 8.1. Can you please suggest the possible fixes to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is installing [TLP](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/tlp.html):

```
sudo apt install tlp tlp-rdw
```

That will automatically optimize power consumption.

If you want to get more involved you can use ***Compiz configuration settings manager*** to reduce visual effects

(**Note: You can break your system with this if you dont know what you are doing!**)

You can also use ***PowerTOP*** to analyze what is using up power on your system.

(Note: Since you have installed TLP ignore the VM writeback timeout in powertop)